# Reexport default import

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

I am writing a JS library. The core file of the library is an ES6 file that exports a default class, which sits in the following location `'./lib/myclass'`

I want users of my library to be able to import the the library from the root of the repository. To achieve this in ES5 I can put the following into an `index.js` file at the root:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/myclass');
```

How can I do this using default exports in ES6? I would also like to use the ES6 way of importing. I realise that I can still do it the ES5 way, but I am just trying to understand how these new statements work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the default export and export it again, as default:

```
import myclass from './lib/myclass';
export default myclass;
```

I believe the following should work as well, at least it compiles in Babel:

```
export {default as default} from './lib/myclass';
```

Comment: I didn't export is as default. Thanks.

Comment: Kudos for doing it in a single line. That is really what I was looking for :) It helps me get my head around it, the more examples I see. Thanks again!